# What the different with this.text = 'a' vs this.setState({text:a'})

Tags: react-native

I've known  the component will re-render when the state change. but in this code:

```
 <ColorPicker
     onColorSelected={color => this.color = color}
     style={{ width: width / 2, height: 200 }}
 />
     <View style={{ width: width / 2, height: 200, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <AnimatedText style={{ fontSize: 25, fontWeight: "bold", color:  this.color }}> asdasdasdasdasd</AnimatedText>
     </View>
```

the no state change but the color of text still change. So what the mean of setState? and the way im doing, is it make better perfomance?

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState({text:a'})` will invoke render method , `this.text = 'a'` will not.

---

react suggest using state props to update ui.

---

`this.text = 'a'` will work just after assignment but `this.setState({text:a'})` will work in batch